# JQuery Not Triggering On Button.click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've written some code that should check a textbox (ID tfa_1) to see if its empty or contains text, this should trigger on a next page button (wfpagenextID6) being clicked.

I've tried replacing my script with an alert("test.") and it dosent appear, so im assuming I have my trigger wrong but I cannot work out what I have done wrong!

My HTML that defines the textbox is below:

```
<input type="text" id="tfa_2685" name="tfa_2685" value="" placeholder="" title="Previous Surname (if applicable) " class="">
```

and the button is

```
<input value="Next Page" type="button" class="wfPageNextButton" wfpageindex_activate="7" id="wfPageNextId6" style="visibility: visible;">
```

Both of these are generated and I cannot change them!

My Script is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#wfPageNextId6').click(function(){
 var inp.Val= $("#tfa_2685").val();
  if (inp.val().length > 0) {
    alert("Test.");
    }
    });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: `var inp.Val` is an invalid syntax

Comment: When you are debugging your code, what does your console say when you run the code?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to assign value to inp variable, you should just do: `var inp = $("#tfa_2685").val();`
And then call to `inp.val()` just replace with `inp`, for inp is not jQuery object so it doesn't have val() method

Answer (score 1):

An identifier ( variable ) must not contains dots. ( see more details   ECMAScript specification in [section 7.6 Identifier Names and Identifiers](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6))

the next variable declaration is wrong

```
var inp.Val= $("#tfa_2685").val();
```

to fix this

```
 var inp = $("#tfa_2685");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#wfPageNextId6').click(function(){
 var inpVal= $("#tfa_2685").val();
  if (inpVal.length > 0) {
    alert("Test.");
    }
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cua40s80/